# How to add output values from a for-loop to a data.frame depending on the variable loop input values in R?

Tags: r, loops, variables, declaration

```
x <- 1
y <- 1
for (y in 1:2){
    for (x in 1:2){

z <- x+y

zresults <- data.frame(x, y, z)

}
}
```

Hello together,

sorry for my dump question, but I am new to R and this is actually my first attempt to code a little bit.

I created a for-loop with the indizes x and y and I want to save the output values (z) together with the corresponding x and y values in a data.frame.
The code posted it is obviously wrong but I'm not getting it.

The data.frame should look like that:

```
  x y z
1 1 1 2
2 2 1 3
3 1 2 3
4 2 2 4
```

Thank you guys a lot in advance!
Greetings from Germany

Comment: The result is that you are creating 4 data frames instead of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution

```
x = 1
y = 1
result = NULL
for (y in 1:2) {
  for (x in 1:2) {
    z = x + y
    if (is.null(result)) {
      result = data.frame(x,y,z)
    } else {
      result = rbind(result, data.frame(x,y,z))
    }
  }
}
result
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do what you want to do:

```
zresults <- expand.grid(x=1:2,y=1:2);
zresults$z <- zresults$x + zresults$y;
zresults;
##   x y z
## 1 1 1 2
## 2 2 1 3
## 3 1 2 3
## 4 2 2 4
```

---

Notes on your attempt:

- The initial assignments to `x` and `y` are not necessary. The values are overwritten on the first iteration of each respective loop with the first value of the RHS vector (`1` in each case). Also worth noting is that, unlike languages like C/C++ and Java, in R you don't have to declare variables; any variable name can be assigned a value at any time.
- In your inner loop you're assigning `zresults`. After the first iteration, you are *overwriting* the previous value that existed for `zresults`. If you want to "build up" a data.frame one row at a time, you can use the following solutions, although note that performance will not be ideal with these approaches:

---

```
zresults[nrow(zresults)+1L,] <- c(x,y,z);
```

or

```
zresults <- rbind(zresults,c(x,y,z));
```

Also note that `zresults` would have to be initialized first, prior to the build-up loop; for example:

```
zresults <- data.frame(x=integer(),y=integer(),z=integer());
```

---

- In general, try to avoid for-loops in R. Instead, vectorization is preferred. There are many good sources on this; for example, see http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html and http://alyssafrazee.com/vectorization.html.